nginx forward wildcard urls
Can someone help me with how to set up an nginx forward that does the following:
This is what I have so far. I was going to adapt it but to be honest I can't get off the ground
location ~* ^/pdf/(.*)$ {
      rewrite ^/pdf/(\d+)*$ /pdf.php;
 }

    

I would like it to :

match any urls that are the in the format

https://example.com/pdf/My-Old-Man
or https://example.com/pdf/My-Old-Man/
https://example.com/pdf/Big-Hamster
or https://example.com/pdf/Big-Hamster/
and forward them to pdf.php


not match calls to pdf.php directly
forward the part /My-Old-Man such that I can read it in my php as part of the '$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']' later on (to query a db)
disallow anything https://example.com/pdf/My-Old-Man/bobchips

I know this is asking a lot, but I think this sort of thing is really useful and I can't see anyone doing it on the internet.

Here is one of the possible solutions:
location ^~ /pdf/ {
    location ~ ^/pdf/(?<name>[^/]+)/?$ {
        rewrite ^ /pdf.php?book=$name;
    }
    return 403;
}
location = /pdf.php {
    internal;
    # your php handler here, e.g.:
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/path/to/php.sock;
}

Requested name should be available as a book query argument inside your PHP script.

you are a immeasurable hero!!! WHAT A MAN!

IVAN THANK YOU !

@MrHeelis I found a flaw in this solution: if someone will request something like /pdf/My-Old-Man/?book=blabla, this request will be rewritten as /pdf.php?book=My-Old-Man&book=blabla. If you don't expect any query string, you can add set $args ""; directive before the rewrite rule; otherwise you can process query string manually considering right book value the very first book= appearance.

I don't need any query strings. It's just for QR Code pdf printing- this will work perfectly with the set $args ""; (every pdf comes with a qr code of where it came from to print more - quite nifty)

@MrHeelis And even simpler - set $args ""; line will not be needed if you add a question sign at the end of the rewrite rule: rewrite ^ /pdf.php?book=$name?;
